# C: MSDN says that "default arguments can be provided for pointers to functions", but is that true?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msdn, default-arguments

Consider [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91563f79%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) MSDN article ('Default Arguments') and the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int x) {
  printf("%d\n", x + 537);
}

typedef void (*Func)(int x = 0);

int main() {
  Func f = print;
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

The article claims that "Default arguments can be ovided for pointers to functions. For example: `int (*pShowIntVal)( int i = 0 );`". As I understood, it means that the code above should compile successfully. However, it does not:

```
a.cpp
a.cpp(7) : error C2383: 'Func' : default-arguments are not allowed on this symbol
a.cpp(11) : error C2198: 'Func' : too few arguments for call
```

Looks like I misunderstood the article. What's the point, what is the correct interpretation?

Comment: I cannot even just say `int (*pShowIntVal)( int i = 0 );` in the code! "error 2383: 'pShowIntVal': default-arguments are not allowed on this symbol"

Answer (score 3):

The default argument is part of a function *declaration* but it is not part of its *type*. So you can write:

```
void f(int x = 0);
```

but the type of f is still

```
void(int x)
```

And consequently, a pointer to function type cannot include default arguments.

(Reference: § 8.3.6/9 [dcl.fct.default]: "A default argument is not part of the type of a function.")

Comment: So the Microsoft's code is non-sense, it is actually invalid C++ code.

Comment: @EarthEngine seems to be the case

Comment: @EarthEngine: correct. Once upon a time gcc accepted default arguments in pointers and typedefs, but it was deprecated a decade ago. I don't know about VC++.

Comment: What i'm reading in MS's stuff is that the variable holding the pointer has a default arg attached.  The type is not affected.  That'd explain the claim that the code in the page would work, while the typedef doesn't.

Comment: @cHao Trust me, I have tried to put this line `int (*pShowIntVal)( int i = 0 );` into my code but it does not compile in VS2013.

Comment: Then it'd seem to be an error in the documentation.  That should probably be reported to MS or something.